# ¿Por qué se define la longitud en un tipo de dato entero?

Tags: mysql

Cuando creamos una tabla y definimos un **tipo de dato entero**, posiblemente definamos una longitud especifica. Por ejemplo:

- `SMALLINT(5)`,
- `INT(11)`, ó
- `BIGINT(20)`

¿Por qué se define esta longitud en un tipo de dato entero?

Comment: Para reservar el espacio necesario según el tipo de dato y no ocupar una gran cantidad de espacio esperando cualquier cosa. Es decir, si sabes que el dato a guardar es un bool, ponerlo como varchar (por ejemplo), es generar un espacio reservado innecesario. Una explicación mejor aquí: https://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/1054.php

Comment: @track3r Lo que comentas es aplicable solo para tipos de datos como por ejemplo: TEXT/CHAR/VARCHAR, y no para números enteros.

Comment: Estás seguro Nicola? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html

Comment: @track3r creo que esta documentación puede explicarlo: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: Entiendo... nunca te acostarás.... Deberías ponerlo como respuesta ;)

Comment: @track3r listo, espero que pueda ser de ayuda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Investigando me conseguí con esta [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) lo cual da una idea bastante clara, probando pude demostrar para que sirve, y la longitud que se define entre paréntesis se llama **atributo**.

Al momento de declarar el tipo de dato entero, el atributo en cuestión se usa para definir la longitud de relleno del dígito "0" a la izquierda cuando se hace un SELECT, y esto solo se puede apreciar cuando defines la columna con la opción ZEROFILL.

En el siguiente ejemplo creo una tabla en la base de datos test llamada demo, vamos a probar con el tipo de dato TINYINT y muestro como se crea por defecto por MySQL, luego se insertan valores y hacemos un ALTER para ver los cambios:

```
USE test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS demo;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo (
  id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  demo TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

SHOW CREATE TABLE demo;
```

Inserto tres valores de diferentes longitudes:

```
INSERT INTO demo (demo) VALUES (127);
INSERT INTO demo (demo) VALUES (12);
INSERT INTO demo (demo) VALUES (1);
```

Ahora hago un SELECT para ver que hay dentro:

```
SELECT * FROM demo;
+----+------+
| id | demo |
+----+------+
|  1 |  127 |
|  2 |   12 |
|  3 |    1 |
+----+------+
```

Modifico la columna para que tenga la propiedad ZEROFILL.

```
ALTER TABLE demo MODIFY demo TINYINT(3) ZEROFILL;
```

Vuelvo hacer el SELECT para ver el cambio:

```
+----+------+
| id | demo |
+----+------+
|  1 |  127 |
|  2 |  127 |
|  3 |  012 |
|  4 |  001 |
+----+------+
```

Como podemos observar, rellena con tres ceros "0" a la izquierda el valor entero. Podemos concluir que se usa el atributo de los enteros con la propiedad ZEROFILL para un aspecto visual.

Comment: Es importante mencionar que el atributo no modifica en absoluto la memoria empleada por ese campo.